# Error: Pasting formed with invalid preprocessing token

Tags: c, arm, concatenation, pasting

I have following code.

```
#define GOTO_RC(row,col) "\033["#row";"#col"H"
#define DISPLAY_WRITE(row, col, fmt, args) printf(GOTO_RC(row,col)  ## fmt, ## args)
```

In example.c I am trying to use it.

```
DISPLAY_WRITE(24,1,"Command:",12);
```

I am getting following error in ARM-MDK tool
[enter image description here][1]
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33MN1.jpg                                                                             error: pasting formed ')"Command:"', an invalid preprocessing token [-Winvalid-token-paste]
error: pasting formed ',12', an invalid preprocessing token [-Winvalid-token-paste]

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to concatenate two strings, get rid of the `##` in `DISPLAY_WRITE`. Two string literals next to each other are concatenated automatically. `##` is for concatenating two tokens together and then interpreting them again as a token, not a string literal.

Also, not exactly related, but if you want to be able to take multiple "args" you're going to need support for variadic macros (most relevant things support them), and do something like this:

```
#define DISPLAY_WRITE(row, col, fmt, ...) printf(GOTO_RC(row,col) fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I deal if I don't have any argument to print. like DISPLAY_WRITE(1,2,"Error"). I want to keep argument section optional. I tried #define DISPLAY_WRITE(row,col, fmt, ...) printf(GOTO_RC(row,col) fmt __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__). though I am getting error expected '('.  I am trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: I worked out. #define DISPLAY_WRITE(row, col, fmt, ...) printf(GOTO_RC(row,col) fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__). Cheers for your help.